# Dynamically matching a string that starts with a substring

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I need to dynamically match a string that starts with `forsale_`. Here, I'm finding it by hardcoding the characters that follow, but I'd like to do this dynamically:

`for_sale = response.html.find('span.forsale_QoVFl > a', first=True)`

I tried using `startswith()`, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Sample `response.html`:

```
<section id="release-marketplace" class="section_9nUx6 open_BZ6Zt">
   <header class="header_W2hzl">
      <div class="header_3eShg">
         <h3>Marketplace</h3>
         <span class="forsale_QoVFl"><a href="/sell/release/XXX" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor">2 For Sale</a> from <span class="price_2Wkos">$355.92</span></span>
      </div>
   </header>
   <div class="content_1TFzi">
      <div class="buttons_1G_mP"><a href="/sell/release/XXX" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor button_3lXdg blue_2acgV button_1YfdK">Buy CD</a><a href="/sell/post/XXX" hreflang="en" class="link_1ctor button_3lXdg grey_1js2e button_1YfdK">Sell CD</a></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _dynamically_ matching?  How is that different than just _matching_?

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't want to statically match `forsale_QoVFl` every time, I want to dynamically match `forsale_*`

Comment: Please edit your question and add a short, representative sample of `response.html`.

Comment: @JackFleeting Sure, just added

Answer (score 0):

`startswith()` is straightforward. `x = txt.startswith("forsale_")` will return a bool, where `txt` is the string you want to test.

For more involved pattern matching, you want to look at regular expressions. Something like this is the equivalent of the `startswith()` line above:

```
import re

txt = "forsale_arbitrarychars"
x = re.search("^forsale_", txt)
```

where if you were to replace `^forsale_` with something like `^forsale_[0-9]*$`, it would only accept ints after the underscore

Answer (score 0):

I assume your final expected output is the link in the target `<span>`. If so, I would do it using lxml and xpath:

```
import lxml.html as lh
sale = """[your html above]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(sale)
print(doc.xpath('//span[@class[starts-with(.,"forsale_")]]/a/@href')[0])
```

Output:

```
/sell/release/XXX
```